# Setting up a test website on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, iis-8

I am developing a Proof of Concept (POC) website for my company and I using asp.net web api for it. I developed the project on my local machine and I want to set it up on IIS on my own machine and give my project manager the address to access it. Unfortunately I never deployed a website to IIS the furthest I went was deleting old log files. Any guide on how if at all possible would be greatly Appreciated.

What I have tried to do so far: 
I installed IIS on my machine and I tried to play around with the add website option and I added the application to the Application Pools. But I am not able to access it with the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several options.

1. If it doesn't have to be at the root of the website, you can always create a virtual directory.  This is generally the easiest thing to do.  The only problem is that you have to make sure when you build your website, it knows how to refer to its files, images, etc. wherever it is located.  HOWEVER, if you already have a full asp.net website deployed at the root, you may have problems with web.config inheritance, etc.
2. Do as Darren said.  The problem here is that if your proof-of-concept needs to be accessed after it's demonstrated, altering the hosts file will not be enough; for any computer that might possibly access the website, IT needs to be able to associate your IP address withever host name you've named your website.
3. Create a website specifically using some preexisting IP or name of your computer as the host header/IPs associated, whatever.   So, you might have one website that answers requests to joe.foobar.domain, and then the other website might answer to joe.foobar, 192.168.2.2... whatever.
4. You can always set up a new website to listen to a different port, like 8080 or something.  Make sure though, that it is a port that wouldn't be in active use, that is, something under 1024. There's nothing preventing you from setting one up under there if the port isn't already being listened to, AFAIK, but it's just not a good idea.

For details beyond this, I think you might want to peruse https://serverfault.com/ and see what answers lie there.

Comment: Thanks I was able to figure it out. I was not making the website into an application and other firewall settings weren't set up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I do this all the time.

1. Create a virtual directory in IIS and name the alias whatever you want, and map it to your website directory.
2. Make sure the website is running (right click on the website you just created in IIS, go to Manage (or something like that), and choose "Browse", as in, browse website.
3. Get the name of your PC by right clicking 'My Computer', go to properties.
4. `http://yourpcname/yourIISAlias` for the website you just created in IIS.

Then give this URL to your boss or whoever, and they should be able to access it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add an entry to the hosts file on any computer that needs to access the site running on your machine. you will also need to set up the bindings of the site in your IIS.

Check this tutorial out http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/Accessing-Local-IIS-Web-Sites-via-Name-using-the-Hosts-File.aspx

Comment: you could just hit it by IP and not worry about the host file since its just a proof of concept

Comment: yep you could do that too. my experience is people tend to not bookmark/remember - where as the url is easier for them.

Comment: This might not even be necessary, depending on his unique situation.  I never had to do any of the things you mentioned...

Comment: Depends if you're all on the same workgroup or not. With this, or the 'IP Only' way, it doesn't matter. Going by computer name would mean they have to be on the same workgroup - from what i understand anyway...